# Global Channel Configuration (Tenant/Banner/Logo)

Tags: java, content-management-system, hippocms

I am wondering how you can create a channel with a base layout where the header logo (banner) and the footer text can be changed globally for all pages in that channel.

I think thats a default use case, that you can at least change the logo of the base layout somewhere globally.

My only idea is to link a layout-document (with the banner infos) in every page but this would be my work-around.

So I need a global channel config where I also can put some tenant specific configuration

Answer (score 1):

You mean to start with a blueprint and then have customizations? One approach would be to define the logo as a channel property. Then in your jsp/ftl you can use that to get the logo.

See also:
http://www.onehippo.org/library/concepts/channels/additional-channel-information.html

Comment: This is a very nice link, thanks a lot! I am going to use it for the configuration. But for the logo problem I think I am going to use a container in the abstractpages/base/top (because its situated in the abstract it will be used by many pages due to the inheritance). This way allows it to set the container once with e.g. a banner view in the abstract base

Comment: There are many ways to achieve the same affect. Whatever works best for your requirements/users is the right way to go. 

Hippo tries to keep its documentation current, but there is a lot so it can be hard to find what you are looking for. We are happy to help even if only to point out our docs. If you do find incomplete, incorrect or missing information please feel free to send a comment.